# Entity Framework alternatives for Cross-Platform Application

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm familiar with Entity Framework as I was working with that in my ASP.NET MVC project earlier. But now I noticed that that xamarin doesn't support EF. What are the alternatives to that?

Comment: it should be supported with sql-lite https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/ or you can try develop it with .net core. https://blog.xamarin.com/building-android-apps-with-entity-framework/

Comment: Having a local db is not an option for me. .NET CORE doesnt seem to work with both iOS and android

Comment: At this point isn't it better to create a data access layer service that will be consumed by both ios and android apps and maybe by a future website?

Comment: Can you give me some resources on how I could do that?

Comment: In this link check out Rest and WCF https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/ here you can find an example interfacing wcf with Xamarin https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/ and here some more RESTful service https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/. Personally I prefer working with Web Api (RESTful) just google web api data access to find some documentation

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect from a phone (or watch or tablet) to a remote repository (remote persistency layer) you can develop a WebAPI app with EF the consume the web services from xamarin

Here you can find very simple example
https://github.com/bubibubi/XamarinCourse.WebAPISample

If you need a local (on the phone) repository the answer is SQLite that has already an ORM on xamarin

Here you can find very simple example
https://github.com/bubibubi/XamarinCourse.SQLite